# How do I get the hyperlink of an answer?

Tags: support, answers, hyperlinks, usability

Is there an easy way to get the hyperlink of an answer?  The only ways I know are:

1. Click an edited link, if the question has more than one revision, and copy the hyperlink of **Return to Answer**.
2. View the page source, look up the anchor for the answer, and augment the URL accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Right below each answer, there's a link that says "link", which links to that answer.
[image]

vvv

Comment: @yhw42: No, that's the "edit" button. :)

Comment: Well, for me, sepp2k's arrow points to the "mod" button but yhw42's points to the "link".

Comment: Thanks!  Usability gripe: "link" isn't an action like "edit", "delete", and "flag" are, so it's sort of misplaced.  I typically look to the "# Answer(s)" header to get the link of an answer (I link to top answers more often than others), but that wouldn't help for other answers.  Maybe "answered ... ago" should link to something.

Comment: @Kenny: It looked fine for me until yours got upvoted... now its the flag button. `:)`

Comment: Now the right place to look is the 'share | edit' links that appear just after the question/answer, and before any comments.  The 'share' link gives you a permanent URL to that item.  _Well, it does so for now, but who knows about the future!_